# DataNucleus, JDO, how to persist my own List implementation?

Tags: java, list, datanucleus

I have written my own java.util.List implementation, and now i want to store it in a MySQL using DataNucleus. My implementation consists of a public class that implements the List interface, and a private class that implements the node for that list.

When I run the SchemaTool in Eclipse, only the table for my Node implementation gets created, and when i run my app, i get the following error:

```
Persistent class "a.b.c.util.DtvList" has no table in the database, but the operation requires it. Please check the specification of the MetaData for this class.
```

Here's the beginning of my List implementing class...

`@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceStrategy.COMPLETE_TABLE)
public class DtvList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements List {
    @Persistent
    private DtvListNode first = null;
    private DtvListNode last = null;
    private int length = 0;
    public DtvList(){};`

Also, i only have an implementation for the `add(E object)` method, all the other methods throw a `RuntimeException`. Could that be the problem?

**PS** I also tried implementing some more methods, such as getIterator and others, and I even tried writing a mapping plugin (http://www.datanucleus.org/extensions/rdbms_java_types.html), but to no avail. The TABLE does not get created by the SchemaTool in the database.

**PS/2** Added the Mapping class for the DtvListNode implementation, now i have a table for the DtvList, but not for the DtvListNode. It is still not working. But i still get the exception  `org.datanucleus.store.exceptions.NoTableManagedException` that the DtvList table does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DataNucleus supports custom List implementation for mapping relationships.

If you Lists are small in size and your implementation can support a copy constructor and to List(), you could map a standard List and implement LoadCallback and StoreCallback to manage the conversion. Obviously if you have a lot of persistent operations on that List, it will get rather messy...